# Python beginner confused by different results in Spyder and VSCode

Tags: python, anaconda, visual-studio-code

I installed Anaconda 3 and VSCode on Win 10 and optimistically following a beginners course called 'Learn Python in One Day and Learn It Well.' Well I had to start somewhere!

I am trying to run one of the demo programs setting up a class as part of my beginners course. I wanted to use VSCode which was recommended but I don't understand exactly what is happening with the terminal window.

The exercise involves setting up a class and then entering an instruction which returns the name value of the instance(?). The demo code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Sep 14 23:07:39 2021

@author: Jon
"""

# democlass

class Staff:
    def __init__ (self,pPosition,pName,pPay):
        self.position = pPosition
        self.name = pName
        self.pay = pPay
    print('Creating Staff object' )

    def __str__(self):
        return "Position = %s, Name = %s, Pay = %d" %(self.position, self.name, self.pay)

    def calculatePay(self):
        prompt = '\nEnter number of hours worked for %s: ' %(self.name)
        hours = input(prompt)
        prompt = 'Enter the hourly rate for %s: ' %(self.name)

officeStaff1 = Staff('Basic' , 'Yvonne' , 0)
```

When I run the file in Terminal(VSCode) the program seems to complete properly, then the next course instruction says:

> Try adding the following lines to Shell and see what happens- **officeStaff1.name**

I am not sure what Shell means as far as VSCode is concerned but if i enter this command in the Terminal it generates an error due to not recognising the command as the name of a cmdlet.

Anaconda also installed Spyder if I run the same code in Spyder and follow the instructions and type:

**officeStaff1.name** at the console prompt I get the correct answer - **'Yvonne'**

I assume that I am either using the wrong VSCode terminal or I have not set up the terminal correctly but I simply cannot work out what I need to do. I think I have the path and the environment set correctly but to be honest the jargon is completely throwing me. I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no typo's in your question then it is because there is a typo in the command that is used in vscod:

```
office staf1.name
```

versus

```
officeStaf1.name
```

And your instance of the object Staff is called officeStaf1.

furthermore check you indentation for you class, you probably want that your `def __str__(self):` and `def calculatePay(self)` methods are part of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, there was a typo in my original post which I have now edited. The command should have read officeStaff1.name

Comment: On further examination you were right about the indentation so I have corrected the code above. That wasn't causing an error when I ran the code and I don't think that was what was causing the difference in outcomes from Spyder and VSCode. In fact I just reran the corrected code in VSC and had the same error when I issued the terminal command - officeStaff1.name.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say VSCode, is this some interactive mode? Because in spyder I assume you use the Iconsole? That is an interactive mode of python, like opening a terminal and then run `python` or `ipython` (if ipython is installed).

Comment: Maybe you have hit the nail on the head here, I didn’t realise there was a difference between Spyder's Console window and VSCode’s Terminal window, however this makes sense. How can I get a similar Interactive terminal in VSCode?

Comment: I Installed the python plugin in VScode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python. Now you can run a file or a line in interactive mode (in my case I select a line and hit `shift+enter`. Also you can install ipython so you can always start an interactive python session in a terminal (also cmd, powershell). Then you enter `ipython` to start the ipython kernel.

Comment: I already had MS-Python installed can run the above code but when I type the command line instruction in the Terminal window - officeStaff1.name I only get the error that it is not a cmdlet... however with the Spyder console, after running the above code, when I type in officeStaff1.name I get the response 'Yvonne'.  Clearly the Terminal window in VSC is not the same as the Spyder console window. This is what is confusing me, am I supposed to enter the command in the Terminal window? I assume that I am not meant to add it to the code window since that would require a print command.